How to Get URL Params in Next.js 15 on the Server Side?
I'm working with Next.js 15 and need to extract parameters from the URL. I was able to do this on the client side using:
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const email = searchParams.get('email');

However, this approach requires the page to be rendered on the client side, while I want to keep the page server-side rendered to use:
export const metadata: Metadata = {}

Is there a way to access URL parameters server-side while still using metadata? How can I achieve this setup?

In your page.tsx take the searchParams as a prop. Remember in NextJS 15 this is async (a Promise) so you will need to await it.
export default async function Page({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: Promise<{ [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }>
}) {
  const filters = (await searchParams).filters
}


In nextjs 15 they require you to additionally wrap your searchParams attribute with Promise and await it within your page.tsx. Here is an example
Nextjs 15+


// /[[...slug]]/page.tsx
export default async function Page({
  params,
  searchParams,
}: {
  params: Promise < {
    slug: string[]
  } > ;
  searchParams: Promise < {
    [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined
  } > ;
}) {
  const {
    slug
  } = await params;
  const sp = await searchParams;

  console.log(slug);
  return ( <
    div className = "w-10 h-10 mx-auto" > {
      sp?.page
    } <
    /div>
  );
}



In the previous versions of Next js this would have been simply:


// /[[...slug]]/page.tsx
export default async function Page({
  params,
  searchParams,
}: {
  params: {
    slug: string[]
  };
  searchParams: {
    [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined
  };
}) {
  const {
    slug
  } = params;
  const sp = searchParams;

  console.log(slug);
  return ( <
    div className = "w-10 h-10 mx-auto" > {
      sp?.page
    } <
    /div>
  );
}



